# "X values grouped in the output in a barchart with seaborn"

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to have a barchart with all the values that I am declaring in the X axis (although they have the same name). However the Output I get in seaborn grouped them all. Could you help me please?

Here is my code which produces the output of three bars:

```
import matplotlib.style as style 
style.use('seaborn-poster')
style.use('ggplot')
processing_times = [15.2875, 15.2539, 1.2172, 1.2116, 21.6022, 23.4139,    1.2097, 1.2067, 30.2567, 27.6683, 2.5, 2.55, 28.5]


selection_type = ['NS', 'NS', 'KFold', 'KFold', 'NS', 'NS', 'KFold',  'KFold', 'NS', 'NS',
              'Stats', 'Stats', 'NS']

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Processing time in hr': processing_times, 'Feature     Selection': selection_type})
ax = sns.barplot(y = 'Processing time in hr', x = 'Feature Selection', data = df )
```

Comment: I would like the output look like not three bars but a bar for every value, no matter if the value in X is repeated, as you can see in my dataset. Thank you very much for the fast answer ;) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close! Use the index to get every value as its own bar.

```
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.index, y="Processing time in hr", hue="Feature Selection", data=df)

ax.set(xticklabels=[]) # Else we'll see arbitrary numbers along the x ax
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem. An additional comment... I would like to have the same color for bars with the same label in the x axis. Is that possible? With the "palette" argument, cannot get the desirable results

Comment: @RogerAlmengor set the `hue` argument as: `ax = sns.barplot(y = 'Processing time in hr', x=df.index, hue = 'Feature Selection', data = df )`